# Access the data in error part of ajax'request

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm making a ajax request to a Django view, on the basis of logic i'm sending the data in response.

```
return JsonResponse(content={
            "Message": "user is not present.",
            },status=400)
```

which comes in error part of ajax request :

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        //access data here
                }
```

How can i access the data in error part of ajax'request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
error: function(xhr){
    alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
}
```